# Nim Game with Arrays

Tags: java, array, heap

I am suppose was to incorporate arrays in my NIM game java code, so that we can allow the user to decide on how many heaps are in play. I am stuck and have no clue how to do so.

Heap Class

```
public class Heap {
private int heapSize;

public Heap(int size)
{
    heapSize=size;
}

public boolean remove(int size)
{
    boolean removed;
    if(size<1  || size>heapSize)
    {
        System.out.println("Pick a number between 1 and "+heapSize);
        removed = false;
    } else {
        heapSize-=size;
        removed = true;
    }
    return removed;
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return heapSize==0;
}

public void displaySize()
{
    System.out.print("\t"+heapSize);
}

public int getSize()
{
    return heapSize;
}

}
```

Nim Class

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nim {
private Heap heapA;
private Heap heapB;
private Heap heapC;
private Random randomNumbers;
public Nim()
{
    heapA=new Heap(10);
    heapB=new Heap(10);
    heapC=new Heap(10);
    randomNumbers = new Random ();
}

public boolean playerMove()
{
    System.out.print("\nSelect a heap: ");
    char heapLetter = input.next().charAt(0);
    Heap tempHeap;

    switch(heapLetter)
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        tempHeap=heapA;
        break;
    case 'b':
    case 'B':
        tempHeap=heapB;
        break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
        tempHeap=heapC;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid heap letter, select a, b or c");
        return false;
    }

    if(tempHeap.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Heap "+heapLetter+" is empty, pick another");
        return false;
    }

    System.out.print("How many do you want to remove? ");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    return tempHeap.remove(number);
}

public void gameMove()
{
    Heap tempHeap;
    boolean valid;
    char select;
    do {
        int heapId = randomNumbers.nextInt(3);
        switch(heapId)
        {
        case 0:
            tempHeap=heapA;
            select='A';
            break;
        case 1:
            tempHeap=heapB;
            select='B';
            break;
        default:
            tempHeap=heapC;
            select='C';
            break;
        }
        if(tempHeap.isEmpty())
        {
            valid=false;
        } else {
            valid=true;
            int size=randomNumbers.nextInt(tempHeap.getSize())+1;
            tempHeap.remove(size);
            System.out.println("Computer takes "+size+" from heap "+select);
        }

    } while(!valid);

}

public void printHeaps()
{
    System.out.println("\tA\tB\tC");
    heapA.displaySize();
    heapB.displaySize();
    heapC.displaySize();
    System.out.println();
}

public boolean gameDone()
{
    return heapA.isEmpty() && heapB.isEmpty() && heapC.isEmpty();
}

}
```

Client Class

```
public class Assign3 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to the NIM cup\nWe play by the normal play rules");
    Nim nimGame = new Nim();
    boolean validMove;
    boolean playersTurn;
    do {
        playersTurn=true;
        nimGame.printHeaps();
        validMove=nimGame.playerMove();
        if(validMove && !nimGame.gameDone()) 
        {
            playersTurn=false;
            nimGame.printHeaps();
            nimGame.gameMove();
        }
    } while(!nimGame.gameDone());
    if(playersTurn)
    {
        System.out.println("Congrats, you win");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you lose");
    }
}

}
```

It is suppose to look like something along the lines of this:

Welcome to the NIM extreme challenge

We play by the normal play rules

How many heaps do you want to have? 100

Error: pick a number between 1 and 26: 0

Error: pick a number between 1 and 26: 3

```
A   B   C

10  10  10
```

Select a heap: c

How many do you want to remove? 10

```
A   B   C

10  10  0
```

Computer takes 6 from heap A

```
A   B   C

4   10  0
```

Select a heap: b

How many do you want to remove? 5

```
A   B   C

4   5   0
```

Computer takes 4 from heap B

```
A   B   C

4   1   0
```

Select a heap: A

How many do you want to remove? 1

```
A   B   C

3   1   0
```

Computer takes 1 from heap B

```
A   B   C

3   0   0
```

Select a heap: A

How many do you want to remove? 2

```
A   B   C

1   0   0
```

Computer takes 1 from heap A

Sorry: you lose

Good bye, thank you for playing

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I voted to close your question as off-topic since you request to add a functionality in your code. Please see the [help] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of your code you have

```
public class Nim {
private Heap heapA;
private Heap heapB;
private Heap heapC;
private Random randomNumbers;
public Nim()
{
    heapA=new Heap(10);
    heapB=new Heap(10);
    heapC=new Heap(10);
    randomNumbers = new Random ();
}
```

I believe you would accomplish what you want if you request how many heaps the user wants and create an ArrayList of objects.  Array sizes must be dictated at compile time, but ArrayLists are auto-resizing.

You want something like...

```
ArrayList<Heap> heapList = new ArrayList<Heap>();
heapList.add(new Heap(10));
```

I'm a little rusty and have never used these, myself.  So this is all theory for me.  You will need to account for and control how many heaps you make, etc.

I recommend you google "java arraylist" and look at several examples.